# Summing counts based on overlapping intervals in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to sum the column for every two minute interval (so it would be the sum of 1,2 and 2,3 and 3,4, etc...), but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

My data looks something like:

```
minute           | source | count
2018-01-01 10:00 |    a   | 7
2018-01-01 10:01 |    a   | 5
2018-01-01 10:02 |    a   | 10
2018-01-01 10:00 |    b   | 20
2018-01-01 10:05 |    a   | 12
```

What I want
(e.g. row1+row2, row2+3, row3, row4, row5)

```
minute           | source | count
2018-01-01 10:00 |    a   | 12    
2018-01-01 10:01 |    a   | 15
2018-01-01 10:02 |    a   | 10
2018-01-01 10:00 |    b   | 20
2018-01-01 10:05 |    a   | 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery selecting the sum of the counts for the records in the interval sharing the source (I guess that the source must match is an requirement. If not, just remove the comparison in the `WHERE` clause.).

```
SELECT "t1"."minute",
       "t1"."source",
       (SELECT sum("t2"."count")
               FROM "elbat" "t2"
               WHERE "t2"."source" = "t1"."source"
                     AND "t2"."minute" >= "t1"."minute"
                     AND "t2"."minute" <= "t1"."minute" + INTERVAL '1 MINUTE') "count"
       FROM "elbat" "t1";
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5245e/8)

Comment: What's an "elbat"?

Comment: @mdahlman: The name of a table I use if an OP didn't tell the name of their actual table (or probably, if I was to blind to see it...). Just read it backwards... ;)

Comment: Ah... Now I get it. I mean, ".ti teg I woN"

Answer (score 0):

the post above assumes all the timestamps are to the minute. if you want to check for every 2 minutes throughout the day you can use the generate_series function.  the issue with including the beginning minute and ending time in each interval will be b having 2 rows in the results.

ie.

```
select begintime,
    endtime,
    source, 
    sum(count)
from mytable
inner join (
    select begintime, endtime
    from (
        select lag(time, 1) over (order by time) as begintime, 
            time as endtime
        from (
           select * 
           from generate_series('2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', interval '2 minutes')  time
        ) q 
    ) q2
    where begintime is not null
) times on minute between begintime and endtime
group by begintime, endtime, source
order by begintime, endtime, source
```

you can change the 'minute between begintime and endtime' to 'minute > begintime and minute <= endtime' if you don't want that overlap